# NullPointerException on getTextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-framelayout

so I have this getter function in a Class called ItemEnergyGreen:

```
public TextView getTextView(FrameLayout fl) {
    textView = (TextView) fl.findViewById(R.id.textview_energyOrange_quantity);
    return textView;
}
```

And I want now to call this methode from another Class:

```
//Item Energy Green
    itemEnergyGreenFrameLayout      = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_energy_green_layout, null, false);
    itemEnergyGreenQuantityTextView = itemEnergyGreen.getTextView(itemEnergyGreenFrameLayout);
    btn_ItemEnergyGreen             = (ImageButton) itemEnergyGreenFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_energyGreenItem_use);
    btn_ItemEnergyGreen.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The function call is in Line 2, I am passing the frameLayout to the getter Function but textView in my ItemEnergyGreen class is always NULL.

The error occurs when i want to call setText on my view:

```
public void itemEnergyGreenUpdateNumber() {
    int quantity = itemEnergyGreen.getQuantity();
    String qstring = String.valueOf(quantity);
    itemEnergyGreenQuantityTextView.setText(qstring);
}
```

This is the XML-FrameLayout that is get inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ItemEnergyGreenFrameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_energyGreenItem_use"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/item_energydrink_green" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_energyGreen_quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#F00"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Why is that?

ps. At the point where the getter function is called, the itemEnergyGreen Object is already initialized.

Thank you for your answers, and sorry if that is a dump question but i´m going crazy about this.

Comment: do you have text set to the textview before you call for it? like in your xml? or even textview.settext? or is it empty?

Comment: Show you XML and log error pls

Comment: Are you sure `TextView` belongs to `item_energy_green_layout.xml`.Post the xml

Comment: i´ve posted the xml and the funcion that is causing the NullPointerExeption

Comment: @DannielR look at the edit in my post you referenced wrong id

Comment: sorry, that was not the problem. I have the same function with an Orange Item. But the problem stays.

Comment: OK.. I am offical stupid :/  That WAS THE PROBLEM.. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> textView in my ItemEnergyGreen class is always NULL.

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current view hierarchy.  Probably `TextView` is not a child of `FrameLayout`. So initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

The other reason could be that you referenced wrong id.

Edit:

Id referenced in wrong

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_energyGreen_quantity"
```

Change this

```
textView = (TextView) fl.findViewById(R.id.textview_energyOrange_quantity);
```

to

```
textView = (TextView) fl.findViewById(R.id.textview_energyGreen_quantity);
```

Comment: @DannielR where do you call this `itemEnergyGreenUpdateNumber()` could be calling before initialization of Textview

Comment: The wrong Id was the error

Thank you very much, such a small detail :(  i need a pause^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private View mView;
 mView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_energy_green_layout, null, false);
 itemEnergyGreenQuantityTextView = itemEnergyGreen.getTextView(mView);
```